# Is \left...\right necessary when there are sub/super-scripts?

Tags: fontsize, delimiters

```
$(a_2+b^3)$
```

or

```
$\left(a_2+b^3\right)$.
```

Which is correct?

An experiment shows that in these two expressions the size of parentheses are different. Is `\left...\right` necessary for correct formatting in this particular case?

Comment: That's the only reason for `\left({...}\right)`... both are correct, in my point of view, but the `\left({...}\right)` does look better (most times), but it's better to use a `{...}` pair in between

Comment: Both are "correct". This is not a good fit for a question, as it seeks an opinion. My guess is you'll find answers rooting making suggestions for both and others as well.

Comment: Definitely the first.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Why the `{...}`? */Confused*

Comment: Some people may prefer `$\bigl(a_2+b^3\bigr)$`...

Comment: @egreg: It's not necessary, of course, but to make it more outstanding while typing/proofreading

Comment: Are large delimiters appropriate in inline maths when not really necessary?

Comment: @cfr: Inline math because the OP wrote $...$ explicitly. My statement about preferring `\left(...` etc was in non-inline-mode

Comment: @ChristianHupfer OK. Thanks. It wasn't clear to me that you meant non-inline given that the question specified inline.

Comment: @cfr: No problem, it was my fault, I should have been more precise

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have no doubt: the answer is *no*.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mleftright}

\begin{document}

$(a_2+b^3)$ \quad $\left(a_2+b^3\right)$

\bigskip

$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$

$a^3-b^3=(a-b)\left(a^2+ab+b^2\right)$

$a^3-b^3=(a-b)\mleft(a^2+ab+b^2\mright)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the first example, there is no need that the parentheses cover the superscript; the formula with `\left`-`\right` sports too big parentheses.

The next example is even clearer, in my opinion. The normal `\left`-`\right` leaves an unwanted space that's corrected with `\mleft` and `\mright` of the `mleftright` package, but still there's no reason why the parentheses around the second factor should be taller.